# Problema con insert en cakephp-mysql

Tags: mysql, cakephp, model

**Codigo controlador**

```
    public function fullClient() {

//        $information = $this->data['Cliente']['informacio'];
        $client = $this->data['Cliente']['cliente'];
        //$posicion_coincidencia = strrpos($cadena_de_texto, $cadena_buscada, -20);
//        $this->Flash->error(__($hola));
        $this->loadModel('Cliente');
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Cliente->create();
            if ($this->Cliente->save($this->request->data)) {
                $consult = $this->Cliente->find('all', array(
                    'conditions' => array('cliente LIKE ' => $client)));
                $id_client = $consult[0];
                $data=array('procesos_id'=>'111',
                    'clientes_id'=>$id_client,
                    'fecha' => getdate());

                $this->loadModel('Necesidad');
                $this->Necesidad->save($data);
                $this->Flash->success(__($client.var_dump("hola")));

                return $this->request->data;
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your post.'));
        }
    }
```

El modelo se llama Necesidad.php y la tabla en la base de datos se llama necesidades, pero al hacer al intentar insertar sale el siguiente error:

[image: Error]

Comment: checa el nombre de la tabla que estas usando por que esta mal escrita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer el problema es como CakePHP está traduciendo al plural la palabra *Necesidad*.
Por ejemplo si ejecuto el siguiente código

```
echo Inflector::tableize('Necesidad');
```

Me imprime la palabra `necesidads`.

Agrega esta linea a tu archivo `Necesidad.php`

```
class Necesidad extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'necesidades'; // Agregamos esta linea con el nombre de la tabla en la base de datos
}
```